# ¿Por qué no me aparece el método last al usar c:foreach o ui:repeat?

Tags: jsf

Estoy intentando realizar una pequeña función que añada una coma o no a un serie de palabras de un array de forma que añada una coma después de cada palabra excepto después de la última. El problema es que cuando uso el valor de la variable varStatus el asistente no me da la opción de usar last y si lo añado yo a mano no realiza la función correctamente.

```
<h:body>
    <c:forEach var="nombre" items="#{indexBean.nombres}"  varStatus="status">
        #{nombre}
        #{status.last ? '': ','}
    </c:forEach>
    <ui:repeat var="nombre2" value="#{indexBean.nombres}" varStatus="status2">
        #{nombre2}
        #{status2.last ? '' : ','}
    </ui:repeat>
</h:body>
```

Por cierto, he probado con Java EE6, EE7, JSF 2.2 y JSF 1.2 .El NamedBean está todo correcto.

Actualmente, me da el siguiente error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagStatus
```

Comment: Has intentado imprimir solo #{status.last} para ver si te esta dando true o false?

Comment: He ejecutado el caso que describes y no tengo ese problema. Ambas opciones con `c:forEach` y `ui:repeat` funcionan. Quizás sea un error de tu IDE. Yo siempre reviso esos archivos como archivos de texto, por ende el IDE no me muestra ningún error. Si el error te aparece en runtime, allí sí hay un problema.

Comment: ¿Puedes pegar el contenido de tu pom.xml si usas maven, o un listado de tus librerías externas si no usas maven? El web.xml también.

Answer (score 1):

He intentado replicar tu escenario y no he tenido problemas. Entorno utilizado:

- Java SE 8
- JSF 2.2
- Servlets 3.1
- Tomcat 8

Configuraciones:

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Clase `FooBean`:

```
//el package no es relevante, omitido
//las sentencias import si son importantes para este caso
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class FooBean {
    private List<String> data;
    public FooBean() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        data = asList("Luiggi", "Vicente", "Gemasoft");
    }
    /getter y setter para data
}
```

Archivo foo.xhtml:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
    <title>Foo example</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <c:forEach var="nombre" items="#{fooBean.data}"  varStatus="status">
        #{nombre}
        #{status.last ? '.': ','} <!-- Agrego un . para que se note que se imprime al final -->
    </c:forEach>
    <br />
    <ui:repeat var="nombre2" value="#{fooBean.data}" varStatus="status2">
        #{nombre2}
        #{status2.last ? '.' : ','} <!-- Agrego un . para que se note que se imprime al final -->
    </ui:repeat>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Salida:

[image: salida al ejecutar la página en Tomcat 8]

Resalto en un cuadrado en rojo los puntos que fueron impresos por `${status.last}` y `${status2.last}` al usar `<c:forEach>` y `<ui:repeat>` respectivamente.

---

Quizás tu IDE te muestre mensajes de error (solía pasarme con NetBeans y Eclipse). Lo que suelo hacer al trabajar con JSF es no confiar en la funcionalidad de autocompletar que ofrecen los distintos IDEs porque es frágil y cuando se rompe parece que todo el proyecto puede explotar. Te recomiendo ejecutar tu código a pesar de que el IDE te muestre problemas o errores en Facelets, si falla en tiempo de ejecución, JSF te mostrará los errores en el stacktrace de manera más amigable que el IDE (en mi opinión).

---

El error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagStatus` significa que te falta la librería de JSTL en tu proyecto. Si trabajas con maven, puedes agregarla de esta manera en tu pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Si trabajas vía ant, deberás agregar la librería manualmente copiando el jar correspondiente dentro de la carpeta WEB-INF/lib

Answer (score 0):

Te falta el **JSTL-api jar**. en tu **pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Puedes descargarlo [Aquí](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl/1.2)  si no usas maven.